# C++ : Copy Array of Structure and return the array of structure

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, structure

I am using Qt Creator to develop an application.

I am not a good C++ programmer, so there might be conceptual errors etc.

I am facing an issue while copying the array of structure and return the structure.

There are ample of solutions related to similar title but could'nt solved my problem.

Here's my code:

**ABC.h**

```
typedef struct command_packet_struct
{
    QString ItemDataName;
    DATA_TYPE ItemDataType;
    int ItemDataLength;
} COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT;

class ABC 
{
private:

    COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT* getHeaderTitle(int index);
    COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT *_packetStruct ;
};
```

**ABC.cpp**

```
COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT _OA_Packet [] = {
    {"ERROR\nMAIN CODE" ,       DATA_TYPE_NUM,          5 },
    {"ERROR\nSUB CODE"  ,       DATA_TYPE_NUM,          4 },
    {"SCALE VERSION"    ,       DATA_TYPE_ASCII,        8 },
    {"E-PRE VERSION"    ,       DATA_TYPE_ASCII,        8 }
};

COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT* PCU_SIM_ORDER_TASK::getHeaderTitle(int index)
{
    int maxSize;

    if (_packetStruct != NULL)
    {
        _packetStruct = 0;
    }

    _packetStruct = new COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT(*_OA_Packet);
    maxSize = ((sizeof(_OA_Packet)/sizeof(COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT)) - 1);
    memcpy(_packetStruct, _OA_Packet, maxSize) ;

    qDebug() << sizeof(COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT);       // return 12
    qDebug() << sizeof(_packetStruct);               // return 4
    qDebug() << sizeof(_OA_Packet);                  // return 48

    return _packetStruct;
}
```

The above code shows the implementation  i have done for Array of structures.

I need to copy array of structure

```
           _OA_Packet
```

to

```
           _packetStruct
```

but when I try to get the size of the **_packetStruct**, it gives **4** while the size of **_OA_Packet** gives **48**

Thus when try to display the contents of the structure, it returns with **"segmentation fault error"**

Any Idea, Suggestion ??

Comment: `_packetStruct` is a pointer. `sizeof` gives you size of the pointer not the size of the memory the pointer points to. The pointer points to a large enough memory location that you allocate to it by using `new`. Also, You shouldn't be using `memcpy` for classes. You should overload the copy assignment operator `=` for the class instead.

Comment: @Alok, thanks for your reply. 
Initially i tried with assignment operator, but the error was same. So  i moved to this concept. Can you provide me some hint/example ? I might have done something wrong in my case ?

Comment: A few points to consider (although not directly related to your problem): 1)All uppercase names are typically used for macros, so you might not want to use that for types (might be confusing for others reading your code). 2) the `typedef struct ...` is useful in C, but unnecessary in C++. `struct COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT {...};` would work just as well. 3) replace `memcpy` with the safer and more easily to use `std::copy` 4) Look into smartpointers to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your struct COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT should be defined like this in C++

   ```
   struct COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT 
   {
    QString ItemDataName;
    DATA_TYPE ItemDataType;
    int ItemDataLength;
   };
   ```
2. use your default constructor to allocate space.

   ```
   maxSize = ((sizeof(_OA_Packet)/sizeof(COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT)));   
   _packetStruct = new COMMAND_PACKET_STRUCT[maxSize];
   ```
3. Copy content.

   ```
   std::copy(_OA_Packet,_OA_Packet+maxSize,_packetStruct);
   ```
4. _packetStruct is pointer, you probably want to check the data size it points to.

   ```
   qDebug() << sizeof(*_packetStruct);               // return 4 -->will be 12
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to copy the complete array of structure stored in "_OA_Packet". So if i take the "sizeof(_packetStruct)" -> should return 48 (i.e. sizeof(_OA_Packet) ). The above code will copy the structure at [index].
pls excuse me if i m wrong. But I need to copy the array of structure stored in "_OA_Packet" to "_packetStruct" and then return this array of structure from the function.

Comment: Hi skg, i updated the code, to copy all content of _OA_Packet to _packetStruct. you also need take note to delete [] packetStruct, otherwise the memory leaks

Comment: thanks for editing. I have one question. sizeof(*_packetStruct) --> gives 12. How to get the size of "_OA_Packet" from "_packetStruct" after copying it. (i.e. _packetStruct should give 48 (size of _OA_Packet) ).
I need the Sizeof _OA_Packet because in the function where I am passing the return Array of structure as an parameter, there i need to retrieve the values from the Array of structure. In order to do so, i should know the actual sizeof the array of structure.
Please provide me suggestion for the same. I really appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: Hi skg, you may have to use some calculation. maxSize*sizeof(*_packetStruct). I don't know any way better.